# Match start or end of string - but only specify pattern once

Tags: c#, regex

Ok, this is mostly an intellectual question (or an improvement).

I have a pattern that must match either start OR end of string (or both).

(Here I simply use '`abcd`' as pattern, but in real world, it's a rather long and complex pattern. However that's not interesting, since it works).

As usual I use this regex:

```
@"^abcd|abcd$"
```

**Here, the pattern is duplicated, once for start and once for end of string.**

However, since the pattern is long and complicated, I would like to **specify it only once in the string**. That would help reading as well as maintaining - I would only have one place to change.

The following regexes do of course not work, but give an idea of what I want:

```
@"^abcd$" - matches only 'abcd' exact
@"^?abcd$?" - matches also 'abcd' in the middle
```

So, the question is:

**Is there a way to match either start or end of string and only specify the inner pattern once?**

Comment: Interesting exercise!

Comment: I deleted my answer. Thanks for pointing out why it was incorrect. I seem to have become fixated on the example.

Comment: A subroutine call is an obvious solution if such are supported by the regex engine. Alas, I understand C#'s otherwise-mighty regex engine does not support subroutine calls, which seems an odd omission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
(^)?abcd(?(1)|$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5E%29%3Fabcd%28%3F%281%29%7C%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=1%20abcd%0D%0Aabcd%201%0D%0A1%20abcd%201%0D%0A&o=m).

**Details**

- `(^)?` - an optional capturing group, its value will be an empty string if the position was matched or null otherwise
- `abcd` - your value
- `(?(1)|$)` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 value is not null (if it was matched) then do nothing, else, match the end of string.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EXpSao):

```
var strings = new List<string> { "1 abcd", "abcd 1", "1 abcd 1"};
var pattern = "(^)?abcd(?(1)|$)";
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", s, Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern));
}
```

Output:

```
1 abcd => True
abcd 1 => True
1 abcd 1 => False
```